# Default Header view for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that is styled as a grouped tableView. Under certain circumstances I need to create a custom view for the header and under other circumstances I want the default one.

Creating a custom header is the easy part - simply use the delegate:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

However, what do I return from this delegate if I want the default header view instead?

I've tried returning nil and this only works as expected when the table view is styled as Plain. If the table view is styled as Grouped then the default header disappears when I return nil.

How do I get the default header back taking into account that I need to sometimes have custom header views too?

**Edit:**

I think I've found the problem. In tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: I do the following:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([myArray count] == 0) return 80;
    else return [tableView sectionHeaderHeight];
}
```

It seems that [tableView sectionHeaderHeight] returns an incorrect height for my header. It sets it to 10 but it should be about 30.

Comment: Under 3.0, the default view is being used when I return nil, even if the table view is grouped. At least here it is.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. It doesn't work for me here. Could you post a sample of your viewForHeaderInSection and your heightForHeaderInSection code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct answer to the above questions is:

To return the default view return nil

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return nil;
}
```

To return the default header height return -1

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return -1;
}
```

That worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question in the edit. I needed to return a hard-coded height for the section header.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want the default header, you should be using following [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"my title text";
}
```

Comment: The question is about the header VIEW, not the text that goes into it.

Comment: @rein you said you want the "default view", which is what you get if you only change the text